# can't see the HTML of a popup window how to interact with it from selenium

Tags: html, selenium, testing, automated-tests, ui-automation

I am trying to select ***Status*** form a new windows popup. After clicking the select status button it opens the dialog page but i can't see the HTML of that page. So not sure how to interact with that dialog page from selenium.

**NB: I have switched to the new window but can't proceed from there.**

***HTML looks like this..***

[image]

***After clicking the select Status button following dialog page opens.***

[image: Select Status Dialog]

but i can see the html of the dialog page so how to interact with it form selenium?

**Update -14/09/17**

When i click on Select Status it call the below url. Opened the url in a separate tab and was able to see the HTML.

> http://xxx.xxx.xxx.int/tasks/status.aspx?CurrFilters=OPEN

[image]

Tried to select a values from the new windows like below...

```
    public void SelectStatus()
    {
        _SelectStatus.Click();
        Browser.Switch_to_child_page();
        _container.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[onclick^='SelectAll']")).Click();
    }
```

**getting following error.**

> Test 'x.RegressionSuite.TestCases.xTest.TC_x' failed:
>   OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : Element is no longer
>   valid

Comment: Is there any frame inside new window?

Comment: The popup is a separate browser instance. Have you tried looking at the HTML that launches the page? Maybe you can get the URL of the page inside the popup and navigate to it directly to get access to the HTML.

Comment: I don't suppose you can share the URL?

Comment: It calls a separate url when i click on Select Status. Updated the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like new windows popup. you can switch to new window. then interact with it.

```
// Store the current window handle
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

// Perform the click operation that opens new window

// Switch to new window opened
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}

//select the checkbox
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath for checkbox")).click();

//click on select button
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath for submit")).click();

// Close the new window, if that window no more required
driver.close();

// Switch back to original browser (first window)
driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```

Comment: I am moving to the new windows but the question is how to select the checkbox as i can't see the html?

Comment: please the get html for new windows using page source or developer tools in the new windows.

Comment: Not sure how can i get the page source as i can't right click on the page. Tried different browsers. If i right click on it there's only two options...
1. Move 2. Close.

Comment: try pressing  F12 to open developer tools. it may works

Comment: No mate, same result. I am feeling like stuck.

Comment: Do you have chance  to looked into the onlick function: SelectFilters(), maybe there is the dialog html file path or url  in code,  if so you can open it in a seperate browser/Tab.

Comment: It calls a separate url when i click on Select Status. Updated the question. Please have a look.